# Selecting a dropbox folder in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I am trying to select a folder in dropbox to download pictures from. Is there any way to programmatically do this in javascript? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to programmatically interact with files in a Dropbox account using JavaScript, you'll want to use the Dropbox API. Dropbox provides an official JavaScript SDK for both datastore and file functionality:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/js
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js#Dropbox.Client

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dropbox api. The documentation can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new, how do I use this?